# Surjective (Onto) functions

Tags: functions

Which is the best way to prove that a given function is surjective or not?

For example, prove that

- $f(x)=2^x$ is not surjective
- $f(x)=3x-7$ is surjective

Both the functions are from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Probably you mean both functions to be from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise it is not clear.

Comment: The words "injective" and "surjective" are meaningless if the two sets involved are not specified.

Answer (score 3):

$(DEF)$: $f: A \to B $ is surjective if for every $b \in B$, there exists some $a \in A $ so that $f(a) = b$.

$Ex 1 $: Let $f(x) = a^x$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Notice, there is not $x$ such that $f(x) = -1 $. It follows that $f$ is not surjective.

$Ex2$: Let $f(x) = Ax + B$. Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Choose $x = \frac{y - B}{A}$. Hence, $f(x) = y$. It follows that $f(x)$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the definition of surjective (given in the answer of Henry).

There are situations in wich the following rule can be a handsome one:

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if and only if a function
$g:Y\rightarrow X$ exists such that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_{Y}$

E.g. if $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto 3x-7$ then notice that $\frac{x+7}{3}$ is sent to $x$. This tells you that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R}$ for function $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac{x+7}{3}$.

This justifies the conclusion that $f$ is surjective (and also that $g$ is injective).

Answer (score 0):

(1) is about showing that a function is not surjective. The best way to do that is to show that there is some element in the range that is not the image of any element in the domain.

In a case like this, to show surjectiveness, I would recommend finding an inverse and show that it is defined on the entire range.